# In R, how to return the value under one column based on a certain rule under another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling, data-management

I have a dataframe in R that looks like this:

| stopping_file | delta |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | 6 |
| 20 | 1 |
| 21 | 1 |
| 22 | 1 |

How could I write a command to return the value "22" under the *stopping_file* column based on the rule that under the *delta* column in an ascending order (from top to bottom) **count three 1s in consecutive**

Thanks for your suggestions in advance!

I tried to use the which command but no idea how to write this rule inside it.

Comment: Here’s a somewhat ugly solution that works for this particular case: `data$stopping_file[data$delta == 1 & c(NA, data$delta) == 1 & c(NA, NA, data$delta) == 1]`. But how do you want to handle it if there are 4 or more `1`s in a row? What if there are multiple runs of 3+ — do you want all of them, or just the first?

Comment: Using dplyr, this would be `data$stopping_file[data$delta == 1 & dplyr::lag(data$delta) == 1 & dplyr::lag(data$delta, 2) == 1]`.

Comment: @zephryl thanks for the insights! this is just a simplified version of my problem. actually I want to return the stopping_file # that corresponds to the 5th consecutive 1 under delta. don't know if that's easier to code in this case?

Comment: @zephryl don't have to use the which command tho...

Answer (score 1):

With the inspiration from @zephryl, I managed to solve this problem proposed by myself.

The exact command to use is:

```
data$stopping_file[data$delta ==1 & lag(data$delta ==1) & lag(lag(data$delta ==1))]
```

For an even more complicated situation: return the stopping_file # that corresponds to the 5th consecutive 1 under delta. The code will be like:

```
data$stopping_file[data$delta ==1 & lag(data$delta ==1) & lag(lag(data$delta ==1)) & lag(lag(lag(data$delta ==1))) & lag(lag(lag(lag(data$delta ==1))))]
```

Comment: Note you can use, e.g., `lag(x, 4)` instead of `lag(lag(lag(lag(x))))`.